# Efficient Ruby LRU cache

Tags: ruby, caching

What's the most efficient way to build a cache with arbitrary Ruby objects as keys that are expired based on a least recently used algorithm. It should use Ruby's normal hashing semantics (not equal?)

Comment: Are you trying for minimal memory use or minimal cpu use, how often are you dropping stuff out of the LRU cache? You can either go the scavenger approach or a double linked list with a paired hash.

Comment: for some ideas see: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html also mongodb has capped collection similarly you can do this stuff with redis. assuming you are looking for a built in ruby solution though

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This pushes the boundaries of my understanding of how Ruby uses memory, but I suspect that the most efficient implementation would be a doubly-linked list where every access moves the key to the front of the list, and every insert drops an item if the maximum size has been reached.

However, assuming Ruby's `Hash` class is already very efficient, I'd bet that the somewhat naive solution of simply adding age data to a `Hash` would be fairly good. Here's a quick toy example that does this:

```
class Cache
  attr_accessor :max_size

  def initialize(max_size = 4)
    @data = {}
    @max_size = max_size
  end

  def store(key, value)
    @data.store key, [0, value]
    age_keys
    prune
  end

  def read(key)
    if value = @data[key]
      renew(key)
      age_keys
    end
    value
  end

  private # -------------------------------

  def renew(key)
    @data[key][0] = 0
  end

  def delete_oldest
    m = @data.values.map{ |v| v[0] }.max
    @data.reject!{ |k,v| v[0] == m }
  end

  def age_keys
    @data.each{ |k,v| @data[k][0] += 1 }
  end

  def prune
    delete_oldest if @data.size > @max_size
  end
end
```

There's probably a faster way of finding the oldest item, and this is not thoroughly tested, but I'd be curious to know how anyone thinks this compares to a more sophisticated design, linked list or otherwise.

Comment: delete_oldest is O(n) which is inefficient, you can do that in constant time if you use another implementation

Answer (score 35):

I know its a few years late, but I just implemented what I believe is the fastest LRU Cache out there for Ruby.

It is also tested and optionally safe to use in multi threaded environments.

https://github.com/SamSaffron/lru_redux

---

Note: in Ruby 1.9 Hash is ordered, so you can cheat and build the fastest LRU cache in a few lines of code

```
class LruRedux::Cache19

  def initialize(max_size)
    @max_size = max_size
    @data = {}
  end

  def max_size=(size)
    raise ArgumentError.new(:max_size) if @max_size < 1
    @max_size = size
    if @max_size < @data.size
      @data.keys[0..@max_size-@data.size].each do |k|
        @data.delete(k)
      end
    end
  end

  def [](key)
    found = true
    value = @data.delete(key){ found = false }
    if found
      @data[key] = value
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def []=(key,val)
    @data.delete(key)
    @data[key] = val
    if @data.length > @max_size
      @data.delete(@data.first[0])
    end
    val
  end

  def each
    @data.reverse.each do |pair|
      yield pair
    end
  end

  # used further up the chain, non thread safe each
  alias_method :each_unsafe, :each

  def to_a
    @data.to_a.reverse
  end

  def delete(k)
    @data.delete(k)
  end

  def clear
    @data.clear
  end

  def count
    @data.count
  end

  # for cache validation only, ensures all is sound
  def valid?
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Remaze has a reasonably well tested LRU Cache: See http://github.com/manveru/ramaze/blob/master/lib/ramaze/snippets/ramaze/lru_hash.rb

And there is also the `hashery` gem by [rubyworks](https://github.com/rubyworks/hashery) which should be more efficient than the remaze one for large caches.

Answer (score 2):

The rufus-lru gem is another option.

Instead of a count it just keeps a sorted array of keys from oldest to newest

Answer (score 2):

I threw together a new gem [lrucache](https://github.com/kindkid/lrucache) which you may find useful. It may be faster than Alex's approach for collections with a significant number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple and fast lru cache I use in our http backend https://github.com/grosser/i18n-backend-http/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/http/lru_cache.rb

Answer (score 0):

`gem install ruby-cache`

--> http://www.nongnu.org/pupa/ruby-cache-README.html